# (Psalm 119:96) understanding what author means by "limit to all perfection"/"consummation of all perfection"

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, layers-of-meaning

> (Psalm 119:94-96  NASB1995 )
>
> 94 I am Yours, save me; For I have sought
> Your precepts. 95 The wicked wait for me to destroy me; I shall
> diligently consider Your testimonies. 96 I have seen a limit to all
> perfection; Your commandment is exceedingly broad.

> (Psalm 119:94-96 New King James Version)
>
> 94 I am Yours, save me; For I
> have sought Your precepts. 95 The wicked wait for me to destroy me,
> But I will consider Your testimonies. 96 I have seen the consummation
> of all perfection, But Your commandment is exceedingly broad.

> 119:94-96 The Westminster Leningrad Codex
>
> 94 לְֽךָ־אֲ֭נִי הוֹשִׁיעֵ֑נִי כִּ֖י פִקּוּדֶ֣יךָ דָרָֽשְׁתִּי׃
>
> 95 לִ֤י קִוּ֣וּ רְשָׁעִ֣ים לְאַבְּדֵ֑נִי עֵ֝דֹתֶ֗יךָ אֶתְבּוֹנָֽן׃
>
> 96 לְֽכָל תִּ֭כְלָה רָאִ֣יתִי קֵ֑ץ רְחָבָ֖ה מִצְוָתְךָ֣ מְאֹֽד׃

As we try to read & understand Psalm 119:94-96 , what is the author of Psalm 119 trying to convey in terms of meaning with the term/phrase "limit to all perfection"/"consummation of all perfection"  ?
Furthermore, could someone please evaluate/assess the Old Testament Hebrew translation of the aforementioned term/phrase, and post an elaborate response on what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the various online internet bible study guides:

> https://www.studylight.org/commentary/psalms/119-96.html
>
> https://biblehub.com/psalms/119-96.htm

> Credit Reference: "Adam Clarke Commentary" ".....Literally, "Of all
> consummations I have seen the end:" as if one should say, Every thing
> of human origin has its limits and end, howsoever extensive, noble,
> and excellent....."

> Credit Reference:  "Albert Barnes' Notes on the Whole Bible"
>
> "......To all claims to perfection made by man, he had seen an end or
> limit. He had examined all which claimed to be perfect; ........."

Most of the commentaries on the aforementioned bible study guide sites seem to suggest/hint/indicate that "limit to all perfection"/"consummation of all perfection" means limits/faults/disadvantages of aspects of our human world(or maybe even humanism).

It's seems like the commentators make an assumption that "limit to all perfection"/"consummation of all perfection" have to do with aspects of our human world(or maybe even humanism).   The reason being is that the 2nd clause of Psalm 119:96 mentions "(God's)Your commandment is exceedingly broad" which indicates some Divine nature/subject.  To elaborate, since it's obvious that the Psalm 119:96's 2nd clause is about a Divine nature/subject, the commentators may have assumed that the Psalm 119:96's 1st clause had to be some kind of opposing comparison.  Therefore, they probably tried to infer/deduce that the "Divine nature/subject" opposite is "humanism/worldliness".

> (Psalm 119:94-96  NASB1995 )
>
> 94 I am Yours, save me; For I have sought Your precepts. 95 The wicked
> wait for me to destroy me; I shall diligently consider Your
> testimonies. 96 I have seen a limit to all perfection; Your
> commandment is exceedingly broad.

However, it would still be interesting is someone else evaluated/assessed the Old Testament Hebrew translations in order to get a better understanding of what Psalm 119:96 was supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

NIV Psalm 119:96

```
To all perfection    I see a limit,   
but your commands    are boundless.
```

perfection || commands
limit || boundless

The concept of perfection, by definition, means completeness, finished, and no more changes. It is done, perfected, the end. It is finite or bounded.

On the other hand, the concept of God's commands is seen here as infinite, boundless, or unbounded.

As we try to read & understand Psalm 119:94-96, what is the author of Psalm 119 trying to convey in terms of meaning with the term/phrase "limit to all perfection"/"consummation of all perfection"?

It is not supposed to be evaluated in isolation. The psalmist meant it as a contrast to God's commands.